# How to render lots of fur that does not fit into memory all at once?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hair, optimization

I'm currently making a short film in Blender with a lot of animals. In a specific scene I have around 10 of them with full groom. The models come from VFX Grace and other stores, they are super high quality. I'd prefer not reducing the hair amount but Blender often gives me "Out of GPU memory" error when trying to render. I have a RTX3080 and 32 GB of RAM.

I've already limited textures to 2K, optimised the poly counts, but don't want to compromise on the hair.

Is my only solution to render on a RTX3090 / 4090 machine or is there a way to optimise the render further? I'm not that familiar with decomposing shots to save memory (background / foreground) but I feel like it's common practice in the industry?

Here is a portion of the shot with only two animals where Blender is already struggling:

[image]

Comment: Since when do RTX3080 cards come with 32GB? :D

Comment: RTX4090 has 24GB of VRAM. There is no guarantee that your scenes are going to fit that. You are rendering with 10 or 12 GB of VRAM currently, depending on the variant of your RTX3080 and you have 2 animals. If you have 5 times more animals(10), that is likely 5 times more fur, so you may need up to 5 times more VRAM... So you might not be able to use GPU at all and may need more RAM for CPU rendering as well if you don't somehow split your scene. It's not uncommon for things like this to require render farm services.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys haha I meant that I have a 10gb VRAM rtx 3080 and 32gb of "normal" RAM ;) thanks for the post edit and answer !

Comment: I was hoping maybe someone else would expand on splitting the scene into layers in a proper answer. That is probably another solution besides rendering on a render farm. I have seen tutorials on that on YouTube. You should be able to find some. It would probably be a long kind of answer here on BSE...

Comment: There are two BVH calculation methods, one is more RAM intensive because it's faster for hair systems, the other is slower but you might at least be able to render..  There's a setting somewhere to switch between them

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off "Use Hair BVH".

Look under Acceleration Structure

Blender Manual: http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/render/cycles/settings/performance.html